# What's the youngest age to play D&D?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, kids

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When and how should I introduce my kids to RPGs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2061/when-and-how-should-i-introduce-my-kids-to-rpgs)

Hi there,

I have four kids aged 11-6. I used to play D&D when in my teams and loved it, and would like to introduce it to my kids (and play again myself, hehe). Are my kids too young? Are there other more suitable rpgs I could play with them?

Thanks