# What Edition of D&D Would be Best for Children?

Tags: dnd-4e, dungeons-and-dragons, edition-comparison, kids

My experience with D&D is not as extensive as most. I used to play 3.5 years ago and have never been in the DM role before. I have six children that are interested in the game that have never played before. Ages range from seven all the way up to seventeen.

I own two D&D books that I found in a Goodwill a year ago. These are the Player's Manual and Dungeon Masters Guide from 4th edition. At first I figured I would just play with this edition however there is a lot of mixed opinions that have got me thinking I need to at least get a good idea of what the differences between the editions are and what would be best for my group.

Now that the background info is out of the way my question stands. What edition would be best for a group of kids? Or am I just overthinking this and any edition should be fine? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. RE: "I have six children that are interested in the game that have never played before." Is it safe to assume that the children are, for the purposes of this question, yours? That is, if you're planning to run the game at a school or daycare center or something discussing first the nature of the role-playing games as a medium with the children's parents and getting their approval to run the game with their kids becomes the *very* first step. Anyway, thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: If I remember correctly, many of the editions of *D&D* included recommended ages, either on the backs or somewhere in their texts. Although it might not yield the answer you were looking for initially, editing this question to something like *What are the recommended ages of the various editions of D&D?* would totally make this question on topic. (It's then not a shopping question and instead answerable with research.)

Comment: This question is kind of related, and may be of help: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2061/when-and-how-should-i-introduce-my-kids-to-rpgs

Comment: this question could easily be re-worded simply to ask how  you could adapt 4e into a game that you could play with kids. I suspect that if the question was edited in that way that you might get at least one good answer that would help in your situation.

Comment: Let me second Oblivious Sage's invitation to chat--I know I'm not the only chat-regular who has GMed multiple editions of D&D--and other RPGs--both for their own children and for others'. (E.g. I run groups both for my son and his friends and for high-schoolers.)